# Summernote - MVC 5 - Getting the Data to model and DB

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-5, summernote

First question go easy!!

I have followed [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/bootstrap-wysiwyg-editor-in-Asp-Net-mvc/) tutorial and managed to get the editor to be visible ok but I cant seem to get the data from the field in question to the model/controller and the DB, rest of the fields work fine.

I did notice that there is:

```
var markupStr = $('#summernote').summernote('code');
```

Stated in the "Getting started" section of the [Summernote site](http://summernote.org/getting-started/) but don't know how to implement it if I am not already.

Question: With the below code should I be seeing data back to my model/controller? If not then what code do I need and where do I put it?

Thanks,
Richard

Here is the code I am using....

Snippet from Model with relevant field

```
<AllowHtml>
<Column("NewsBody")>
<Display(Name:="News Body")>
Public Property NewsBody As String
```

Snippet from Control

```
        If ModelState.IsValid Then
            db.NewsModels.Add(newsModels)
            db.SaveChanges()
            Return RedirectToAction("Index")
        End If
        Return View(newsModels)
```

Snippets from view

```
     <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.NewsBody, htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "control-label col-md-2"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.NewsBody, New With {.htmlAttributes = New With {.class = "form-control", .id = "NewsBody", .name = "NewsBody"}})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.NewsBody, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
        </div>
    </div>
```

Bottom of view

```
@section scripts  
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/summernote", "~/Scripts/NewsEdit.js")
End section
```

NewsEdit.js

```
(function ($) {
function HomeIndex() {
    var $this = this;

    function initialize() {
        $('#NewsBody').summernote({
            focus: true,
            height: 150,
            codemirror: {
                theme: 'united'
            }
        });
    }

    $this.init = function () {
        initialize();
    }
}
$(function () {
    var self = new HomeIndex();
    self.init();
})
}(jQuery))
```

Snippet from BundleConfig

```
        bundles.Add(New StyleBundle("~/Content/summernote").Include(
                "~/Content/summernote/summernote.css"))

        bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/summernote").Include(
                "~/Content/summernote/summernote.js"))
```

Snippet from _layout.vbhtml

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/summernote")
```

Edit based on Malcor's comment, thanks :) :
Below is my simple code for the reciving controller. The model is returning ok but the field being used by Summernote comes back NULL. I think my problem is that I don't know how to send data to or pull data back from the Summernote.

```
<HttpPost()>
    <ValidateAntiForgeryToken()>
    Function Create(<Bind(Include:="Id,NewsTitle,NewsSummary,NewsBody,NewsCreatedBy,DateNewsCreated,NewsEditiedBy,DateNewsEditied,NewsVisable,PromoteNews")> ByVal newsModels As NewsModels) As ActionResult

        If ModelState.IsValid Then
            db.NewsModels.Add(newsModels)
            db.SaveChanges()
            Return RedirectToAction("Index")
        End If
        Return View(newsModels)
    End Function
```

Comment: Could you add the entire Action that handles adding the model to the database. Is it when you're in the action adding to the database that you're having issues, you're not getting a complete model from the view?

Comment: Thanks Malcor, added it, anything else let me know.